# How to word a survey question comparing alternative purchase choices?

Tags: survey, likert

I'm creating a survey to ask a customer that just bought a product what other products they considered before buying and how seriously they considered them.  I'd like to use a [Likert scale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Likert_scale) type of answers, but am having trouble selecting.  Thus far I the question looks like this:

```
                  Strongly  |            |          | Strongly | Did not consider
                 Considered | Considered | Rejected | Rejected |  / Not Familiar
Competitor A
Competitor B
Competitor C
Competitor Other
```

I'd really like at least five answers with knowledge, with another added between `Considered` and `Rejected`. However, using `Neutral` between those I'm afraid sounds too much like `Did not consider / Unaware of choice`.

I'm also concerned that I'm mixing `Considered` with `Rejected`, because you must first consider before you reject and this might confuse respondents.  What other pairs of opposite words might I use instead?

Are there any commonly accepted examples in the art of a question like this that I could model mine after?

Answer (score 0):

You can always phrase the question so the response will become strongly agree to strongly disagree. For example, your stem can be: "Please answer on a scale from strongly agree to strongly disagree, the following statement: I considered buying _____ before buying the product."

Or, you can stick to considered and rejected, but not label the points between them. Some people think this is a better idea if you intend to treat the variable as continuous because it is arbitrary whether the distance between strongly considered vs considered and considered vs neutral is the same.

Comment: Since the survey is being given verbally over the phone, I cannot use unlabeled middle items.  Also whether you could have strongly considered buying the product and after looking into it, strongly rejected buying it based on reviews you read, etc.